# Why does my code run multiple times when button is pressed?

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

With MicroPython and a Raspberry Pi Pico I have a button which fires multiple times when pressed. How can I make the button execute the code just once?

```
from machine import Pin
import utime

button = Pin(3, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

def my_handler(button):
  print("hello")
  utime.sleep(1)

button.irq(trigger = machine.Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler = my_handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a helpful article here that solved my problem

https://www.coderdojotc.org/micropython/advanced-labs/02-interrupt-handlers/

By measuring the time between the button being pressed I could stop the code firing multiple times.

```
last_time = 0

button = Pin(3, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

def my_handler(button):
    global last_time
    new_time = utime.ticks_ms()
    # if it has been more that 1/5 of a second since the last event, we have a new event
    if (new_time - last_time) > 400: 
        print("hello")
        last_time = new_time
```